# How can I correct this Hamming code?

Tags: error-correcting-codes, hamming-code

I'm trying to decode the following Hamming sequence (using EVEN parity and knowing there is a 1-bit error), which contains an ASCII value: `01100110101`

I've tried to check for the correctness of each parity bit:

```
    p1 p2 d3 p4 d5 d6 d7 p8 d9 d10 d11
     0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1   0   1
p1 - 0     1     0     1     1       1
p2 -    1  1        1  1         0   1
p4 -          0  0  1  1
p8 -                      0  1   0   1
```

p1, p4 and p8 checks are all even and correct.

p2 check is odd, hence the parity bit is incorrect and needs to be flipped. The actual message then becomes `00100110101` and the ASCII value can be read as `1011101`.

Supposedly this value is incorrect - can anyone point out the mistake I made?

Comment: Wouldn't Hamming Code be more appropriate in the [Signal Processing StackExchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @KingDuken It is perfectly appropriate in either.

Comment: @polyethene Why do you think that this is wrong? It looks correct. Since `p2` has the only odd sum, the bit `p2` itself has to be wrong (all the other bits are used by at least 2 controll sums, which would mean that at least two bits are wrong).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/96118/755, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/51161/5874.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @KingDuken, in the future, may I request that if you are going to suggest a different site, please let the poster know not to cross-post?  You can suggest they delete the copy here before posting elsewhere.  Hopefully that will provide a better experience for everyone.  (But in this case, it is on-topic here, so there's no reason to move it.)  Thank you for listening.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to describe where you got the idea that this is incorrect.  If someone told you that, maybe they are wrong.  If you read it somewhere, maybe whatever you read was in error.

Comment: @D.W. I've deleted the SE.DSP copy. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Ah will know for future reference. @Jakube This is from a quiz on my university's LMS, the site is saying my answer is incorrect.

Comment: The usual Hamming code has length of the form $2^\ell-1$. Perhaps you can describe what "Hamming sequence" means for you?

Comment: ASCII values are 8-bit (or 7-bit). You have 11 bits.

Comment: Someone (this OP?) will pay 10 dollars if you answer the question [here at reddit.com](https://www.reddit.com/r/slavelabour/comments/96lyw5/task_answer_these_questions_computer_science_10/?ref=readnext)

Comment: @Yuval I meant Hamming code, I can see how that might refer to something else so I've updated the question.

Comment: Yes it's a Hamming code that contains an ASCII value.

Comment: Lol I'm not paying anyone $10 for this, the bounty still stands though. Person who posted that is probably from my university.

Comment: Here is a possible situation. An answer appears here. Someone use it (after modifying it if needed/desired to claim his/her originality) to bid for the question at reddit.com.

Comment: I know the basics of Hamming codes, and but I can't understand your question because I don't remember what p1, p2, p4, and p8. If you included some more context (the definition of Hamming code from your notes, for example, with encoding and decoding) that might help get answers.

Answer (score 2):

The **original problem** is, I believe, the following.

> When using Hamming code with EVEN parity for 7-bit ASCII characters, the following symbol is retrieved: 01100110101.
>
> Assuming a 1-bit error, what was the original stored symbol? Write down your answer as a 7-bit binary, with no spaces.

OP's statement, "..., which contains an ASCII value: 01100110101", rephrases the original problem statement in a slightly confusing way,  as pointed out by Yuval Filmus.

**OP's procedure and result is correct**, as said in [Jakube's comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/96118/91753#comment-204775) and indicated in [D.W.'s comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/96118/91753#comment-204781%22). I have verified it as well according to [Hamming code at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code).

OP's procedure and result will not be repeated here.

Someone mentioned that "The usual Hamming code has length of the form $2^\ell−1$". For $\ell=4$, the usual Hamming code of length 15 is defined by the following table from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code).  If we truncate the last 4 columns, we will get the truncated Hamming code of length 11, which should be, presumably, the Hamming code used in OP's question.
[image: table of general rules to generate a single-error correcting Hamming code of length 15]

**"Supposedly this value is incorrect - can anyone point out the mistake I made?"**

This is the turning point to the climax (or anti-climax). There are four possibilities.

1. **A different kind of (truncated) Hamming code is used**.
   For example, all four parity bits could have been specified to be put together in the first four bits. That is, the first four bits, 0110 are the usual p1, p2, p4 and p8 parity bits while the remaining 0110101 are the data bits. In that case, we rearrange the bits to form the usual Hamming code as `(p1)(p2)0(p4)110(p8)101`, which is `01011100101`. Then p1, p2, p4 check are odd while p8 is OK. So we flip the $1+2+4 =7$-th bit to obtain 01011110101. So the corrected data bit will be 0111101. Well, OP can check if this or something similar is the case.
2. "This is from a quiz on my university's LMS, the site is saying my answer is incorrect."
   As D.W. suggested, **maybe they are wrong. Maybe whatever you read was in error**. There might be a typo in the statement of the quiz. There might be an error in the original answer by the quiz owner. There might be an error in the answer-checking process by the site. There might be a critical typo in OP's post. And so on.
3. Jakube, D.W., I, and, apparently, many others have not been able to find the mistake. That is very unlikely, though.
4. The last possibility stands for, as always, all other probably even lesser possibilities.